# No support of elastic search river with informix

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch, informix, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

When i try to connect the elastic search jdbc river plugin with postgres or h2 db to get the data into the elastic search engine, it behaves properly.

But in case of informix it always give this kind of error :-

**java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:informix-sqli:**

even after i put the jar file into the plugin/jdbc folder.

can anybody has any idea on that.

Comment: Have you put there 6 jar files needed for Informix? Are you able to connect to Informix with simple Java or Jython test program?

Comment: The issue was with the Jar, i had all the 6 jars but the thing wat elastic search engine accepts a jar in specific way which means jar sould contail Meta-Inf->services->jdbc.sql.Driver, which was not there so explicitly i had mension the driver name in the elastic search configuration. which is set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djdbc.drivers=com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the Jar, I had all the 6 jars but the thing wat elastic search engine accepts a jar in specific way which means jar should contail Meta-Inf->services->jdbc.sql.Driver, which was not there so explicitly I had mension the driver name in the elastic search configuration. which is 
**set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%** **-Djdbc.drivers=com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver**